# Building URL from input value using PHP

Tags: php, html, input

**Site1:** http://www.sitea.com

**Site2:** http://www.siteb.com

I would like to use the **input field value** from **Site1** to build an url within a `<a href="">` element that will point to **Site2**. This will be used to access search functionality of another site.

**Example:**
input value = test-search

**URL:** http://www.siteb.com/#!q=test-search?parameter1

**My attempt look like this:**

```
    <form action="index.php" method="GET">
        <input type="search" name="search" />
    </form>
    <a href="https://www.siteb.com/#!q=<?php echo $_GET['search']; ?>?parameter1">Search</a>
```

I was looking through different tuttorials but could not find one that will use PHP to pass the value of the input field and build the URL.

**Please note:** I am limited to PHP only and no JS at all.

**AMP example:** - [link to example](https://ampbyexample.com/components/amp-form/)

```
<form method="GET"
  class="p2"
  action="/components/amp-form/submit-form"
  target="_top">
  <div class="ampstart-input inline-block relative mb3">
    <input type="search"
      placeholder="Search..."
      name="googlesearch">
  </div>
  <input type="submit"
    value="OK"
    class="ampstart-btn caps">
</form>
```

Comment: I'm confused - what is your actual question here?

Comment: I would like on entering data in input field and pressing submit to go to another page with specific URL that will contain the value entered in the input field as well.

Comment: How is your attempt differing from your desired output? Using echo and the $_GET[''] variable is a standard way of doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your main index.php file you will have this

```
<form method="GET"
      class="p2"
      action="submit-folder"
      target="_top">
    <div class="ampstart-input inline-block relative mb3">
        <input type="search"
               placeholder="Search..."
               name="googlesearch">
    </div>
    <input type="submit"
           value="OK"
           class="ampstart-btn caps">
</form>
```

and inside a folder named "submit-folder" with another index.php file inside yo will have this

```
  <?php
if (isset($_GET["googlesearch"])) {
    header("Location: https://www.siteb.com/#!q=" . $_GET["googlesearch"] . "?parameter1");
}
```

this is the file that will receive the request then automatically redirect you could have done this in a single file though as

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET["googlesearch"])) {
    header("Location: https://www.siteb.com/#!q=" . $_GET["googlesearch"] . "?parameter1");
    exit;
}
?>
<form method="GET"
      class="p2"
      action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>"
      target="_top">
    <div class="ampstart-input inline-block relative mb3">
        <input type="search"
               placeholder="Search..."
               name="googlesearch">
    </div>
    <input type="submit"
           value="OK"
           class="ampstart-btn caps">
</form>
```

Comment: did you place the above code in a php file, plus this should automatically redirect you to the second site after clicking search

Comment: Yes its working on this side after you hit submit you are automatilly redirected

Answer (score 1):

You have to make redirect in you action script:

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['search']))
    header("Location: https://www.siteb.com/#!q=".$_GET['search']."?parameter1"); 
?>
```